# Fullcalendar - selected day border

Tags: css, fullcalendar

When I select a day on the fullcalendar, I want to place a border around it. However I do this it doesn't draw the entire border, it never shows the bottom line.

Comment: can you add some code, examples jsfiddle, and security social number to improve this question?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
.fc-day-grid{
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doens't work yet, I already placed a border of 4 px solid black around it, and even when I add the border-bottom of 5 px it doens't work.